# C++: Defining a struct that holds containers defined by templates to types defined by the struct

Tags: c++

I would like to define a struct `Primitives` that contains containers that hold non struct-templated types as I tried to bellow. The structs `Sphere`, `Plane` and `Triangle` are all defined before this struct as well as the enum `Device`. I would like for the container of these types to be templated by the user of the struct without specifying the types they hold as the struct should do that. An arbitrary container type might looks like (in my case since I'm abstracting CUDA host/device memory):

```cpp
template <typename T, Device D>
struct my_container {
    /*...*/
};
```

And the `Primitives` class I would like to define looks like:

```cpp
template <typename Container, Device D>
struct Primitives {
    Container<Sphere, D>   spheres;
    Container<Plane, D>    planes;
    Container<Triangle, D> triangles;
}; // Primitives
```

When I compile it with `nvcc` on windows which uses `cl.exe`, I get the error message:

```
error: template parameter "Container" may not have a template argument list
```

I understand why I get this message but I don't know if there is a way to achieve what I want to do.

Comment: What you're looking for is a "template template parameter" - a template parameter that is a placeholder not for a concrete type, but for a template type!  That's what your `Container` template parameter is: a placeholder for a _template type_. See this page https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters (and there are other pages as well) describing how you do this.

Comment: thanks! Could you give an example of how I could make it work?

Comment: Yes it does! I found it quite hard to search for it.

Comment: As usual, you kind of have to know the answer - or at least what it is _called_ - before you can find it!